# Convert arrival data from short period into generator function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing arrival times for a 24h window. By plotting the data, I notice that it seems to be roughly linear. I would like to convert this into a generator in python.

Plotted data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JB4m.png

```
Arrival data in min of day:
287.73
302.17
318.03
357.66
389.87
392.82
395.99
406.47
446.29
466.47
...
1341.88
1342.17
1348.14
1348.76
1369.15
1384.69
1390.71
Day ends at 1440mins
```

How do I convert this 24h data into a generator function such that I can generate the next arrival time each time I call the function even past the original 24h period? It does not need to be a linear function, might be exponential as well.

I was thinking of extrapolating the data into a large df set but that seems rather inefficient on memory and I am also unsure how to extrapolate it this way too.

```
def generator(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        yield row['time']
```

Answer (score 1):

(edited: improved output format from generator)

You would probably want to do a linear regression for this.

The idea is to train a model on your data set to learn the function.  This is called "fitting" the model. Then you can use this model to predict future arrival times.

Here is an example:

I will assume your dataframe looks like this:

```
    0
0   20.130714
1   37.598029
2   46.015164
3   52.042456
4   64.218346
5   58.528393
....
145 1296.520794
146 1320.282179
147 1327.387859
148 1326.318235
149 1337.973246
```

where the first column is the index and the second is the arrival times.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

def generator(df):
    X = df.index.values.reshape(-1,1)
    y = df.values

    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X,y)

    i=1
    while True:
        yield np.asscalar(reg.predict(X[-1].reshape(1,-1)+i))
        i+=1
```

Testing:

```
for i,v in enumerate(generator(df)):
    print(i,v)
    if i == 10:
        break
```

Yields:

```
0 1358.2313994853853
1 1367.2216112477986
2 1376.2118230102114
3 1385.2020347726243
4 1394.1922465350372
5 1403.1824582974505
6 1412.1726700598633
7 1421.1628818222762
8 1430.1530935846895
9 1439.1433053471023
10 1448.1335171095152
```

Comment: I understand that it is a linear regression but is there a way to keep the noise that is present in the base data? Right now the generator returns with a fixed interval which makes it somewhat unrealistic in modeling real world data. Perhaps another predictor class?

Comment: Then it’s not linear anymore , so you could always try a neural net if you want to try to capture more complexity.

Comment: I plotted a histogram of df.diff() and it looks to me like an exponential distribution. Is there a model that fits such a distribution? https://i.imgur.com/kJnNrFM.png